# Лишние символы при инициализации символьного массива

Tags: c++, char

Вопрос в том, как себя ведёт массив символов, объявленный с каким-то конкретным размером **n** в момент, когда мы пытаемся его инициализировать с клавиатуры и вводим строку длинной **>n**?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    char str[10];

    gets(str);

    std::cout << str << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Если в данном примере мы объявили символьный массив `str` с размером **10**, а потом методом `gets()` ввели строку, например, "hello, world!" размером **14** (вместе с '\0'), то `cout` выдаст результатом всё же "hello, world!". Вопрос - почему так? Ведь размер исходного массива был объявлен **10**.

Comment: Потому что где-то в памяти будут лежать все 14 символов... Пусть и за пределами выделенной памяти.

Comment: а теперь понимаете, почему gets считается опасной?

Comment: Понял, спасибо!

Comment: `Если в данном примере мы объявили символьный массив str с размером 10, а потом методом gets() ввели строку, например, "hello, world!" размером 14`, то поведение программы не определено. Может произойти что угодно. Например, 1) программа может работать в соответствии с вашими ожиданиями, 2) программа может аварийно завершиться, 3) на вашем компьютере может самозародиться Скайнет, который начнёт ядерную войну против человечества, 4) будет наблюдаться какое-то иное поведение.